# How to check receipts (In-App Purchase) before launch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, subscription

I want to check receipts before launch app in Swift. At first I wrote the code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, `AppDelegate`. But it finish checking it after the first `ViewController` appeared. 
I want to change moves depends on whether In-App Purchase (Subscription) is valid or not.

How can I implement it?

**AppDelegate**

```
import StoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SKPaymentManagerDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        SKProductManager.getSubscriptionProduct()

        SKPaymentManager.shared().delegate = self
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(SKPaymentManager.shared())

        SKPaymentManager.checkReceipt(handler: { valid in
            receiptValidation()
            isSubscriptionValid = valid
            hideBlock(isValid: isSubscriptionValid) //if subscription is valid, hide all "block" objects in App

            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        })
    return true
}
```

**SKProductManager**

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

fileprivate var productManagers : Set<SKProductManager> = Set()

class SKProductManager: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    static var subscriptionProduct : SKProduct? = nil

    fileprivate var completion : (([SKProduct]?,NSError?) -> Void)?

    static func getProducts(withProductIdentifiers productIdentifiers : [String],completion:(([SKProduct]?,NSError?) -> Void)?){
        let productManager = SKProductManager()
        productManager.completion = completion
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(productIdentifiers))
        request.delegate = productManager
        request.start()

        productManagers.insert(productManager)
    }

    static func getSubscriptionProduct(completion:(() -> Void)? = nil) {

        guard SKProductManager.subscriptionProduct == nil else {
            if let completion = completion {
                completion()
            }
            return
        }

        let productIdentifier = "secret" 

        SKProductManager.getProducts(withProductIdentifiers: [productIdentifier], completion: { (_products, error) -> Void in
            if let product = _products?.first {
                SKProductManager.subscriptionProduct = product
            }
            if let completion = completion {
                completion()
            }
        })

    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        var error : NSError? = nil
        if response.products.count == 0 {
            error = NSError(domain: "ProductsRequestErrorDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"couldn't get product"])
        }
        completion?(response.products, error)
    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        let error = NSError(domain: "ProductsRequestErrorDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"couldn't get product "])
        completion?(nil,error)
        productManagers.remove(self)
    }
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
        productManagers.remove(self)
    }
}
```

**SKPaymentManager**

```
///...
public static func checkReceipt(handler:@escaping (Bool)->()) {

var date = NSDate()
var check = false

do {
    let reqeust = try getReceiptRequest()
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: reqeust, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard let jsonData = data else { return }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .init(rawValue: 0)) as AnyObject
            receiptStatus = ReceiptStatusError.statusForErrorCode(json.object(forKey: "status"))
            guard let latest_receipt_info = (json as AnyObject).object(forKey: "latest_receipt_info") else { return }
            guard let receipts = latest_receipt_info as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }
            updateStatus(receipts: receipts)
            var latest = receipts.last

            date = NSDate()
            if let result = latest!["expires_date"] as? String {
                let expireDate = result
                check = checkDifference(now: date, expireDate: expireDate)
                let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.isValid = check
            }

        } catch _ {
           handler(false) 
        }
    })
    task.resume()
} catch let error {
    print("SKPaymentManager : Failure to process payment from Apple store: \(error)")
    checkReceiptInLocal()
    handler(false)
}

return check

}

/// check subscription is valid or not
fileprivate static func checkDifference(now: NSDate, expireDate: String) -> Bool{

    // convert string to Date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
    let expire = dateFormatter.date(from: expireDate)

    let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.year,.month,.weekOfMonth,.day,.hour,.minute,.second]
    dateComponentsFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
    dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .full

    dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: now as Date, to: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 4000000))  // "1 month"
    dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: expire!, to: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 4000000))  // "1 month"

    let seconds = expire?.seconds(from: now as Date)  

    if seconds! > 0 {
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }

}
///...
```

Comment: It takes time to check the receipt and it may not even succeed due to network issue or server problems. Your app must respond in some way long before the attempt to check completes (regardless of success or failure). So show some user interface while the check completes in the background. Update the user interface accordingly based on the result.